# Can someone explain how this loop is printing this tuple?

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand the solutions to question 5 from pythonchallenge, but I don't understand how the for loop is printing that data from the tuple. The solution is from [here](https://www.hackingnote.com/en/python-challenge-solutions/level-5)

Data contains a list of tuples, eg. `data = [[(' ', 95)], [(' ', 14), ('#', 5), (' ', 70), ('#', 5), (' ', 1) ...]]`

```py
for line in data:
    print("".join([k * v for k, v in line]))
```

What should be printed out is an ASCII graphic made up of '#'.

Comment: What is the question here? Looks to me like you are missing some code.

Comment: You do understand that `'#' * 5` produces a string of five `#` signs?

Answer (score 0):

This one is sneaky. It's a list of lists of tuples. The inner list is a row on the terminal, and each tuple is a character followed by the number of times that
character should be printed.

It looks like it's iterating through the list, and for each tuple,
printing out tuple[0] tuple[1]-times.

It prints '' 95 times, then '' 14 times, then '#' 5 times, etc, inserting newlines
inbetween each inner list.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
>>> line = [(' ', 3), ('#', 5), (' ', 3), ('#', 5)]
>>> strs = [k * v for k, v in line]
```

Then:

```
>>> strs
['   ', '#####', '   ', '#####']
```

Furthermore:

```
>>> ''.join(strs)
'   #####   #####'
```